# TypeFamilies or GADTs suddenly breaks the valid code

Tags: haskell, type-inference, gadt, type-families

I have very innocent-looking code

```
data Config = Config
    { cInts    :: [Int]
    , cStrings :: [String] }

instance Semigroup Config where
    c1 <> c2 = Config
        { cInts    = andCombiner cInts
        , cStrings = andCombiner cStrings }
      where
        andCombiner field = field c1 <> field c2
```

It compiles and works fine. However if I add `TypeFamilies` or `GADTs` extension I see very strange error:

```
.../Main.hs:19:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: [String]
        Actual type: [Int]
    • In the ‘cStrings’ field of a record
      In the expression:
        Config {cInts = andCombiner cInts, cStrings = andCombiner cStrings}
      In an equation for ‘<>’:
          c1 <> c2
            = Config
                {cInts = andCombiner cInts, cStrings = andCombiner cStrings}
            where
                andCombiner field = field c1 <> field c2
   |
19 |         , cStrings = andCombiner cStrings }
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

.../Main.hs:19:34: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: Config -> [Int]
        Actual type: Config -> [String]
    • In the first argument of ‘andCombiner’, namely ‘cStrings’
      In the ‘cStrings’ field of a record
      In the expression:
        Config {cInts = andCombiner cInts, cStrings = andCombiner cStrings}
   |
19 |         , cStrings = andCombiner cStrings }
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

What can be the reason for this compiler error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is due to [`-XMonoLocalBinds`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XMonoLocalBinds) which `-XGADTs` and `-XTypeFamilies` imply. You can get your code to compile again by adding a type signature to `andCombiner` (or by turning on `-XNoMonoLocalBinds`, although I do *not* recommend that):

```
instance Semigroup Config where
    c1 <> c2 = Config
        { cInts    = andCombiner cInts
        , cStrings = andCombiner cStrings }
      where
        andCombiner :: Semigroup a => (Config -> a) -> a
        andCombiner field = field c1 <> field c2
```

Using the terminology from the GHC docs I've linked, `andCombiner` is not fully generalized because it mentions `c1` and `c2` which are not closed or imported.

Comment: Do you mean turn `-XMonoLocalBinds` *off*, with `-XNoMonoLocalBinds`?